# porqué me aparecen errores en líneas que no se pueden editar?

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una calculadora con netbeans, y me aparece error en una línea que no me deja editar ya que es del código de uno de los botones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien me puede ayudar o le paso lo mismo, la mejor. <333

Comment: Hola. No se entiende qué es lo que quieres editar, ni qué archivo es ni dónde se encuentra ubicado. Por ejemplo, hay algunos archivos que son autogenerados, esos archivos no puedes editarlos, debes editar los archivos del código fuente, que suelen estar en la carpeta `src`. Pulsa [edit] y clarifica tu problema.

Comment: holaa! no quiero editar nada, necesito que ese error deje de aparecer para poder ejecutar el proyecto, pero no sé cómo editas los archivos del código fuente, la carpeta src la encontré, pero no sé qué tengo que editar puntualmente..

Comment: Pues tienes que corregir el o los archivos que tienen error. ¿Cuál es ese o esos archivos que te dan error?

Comment: Hola zoeee77, bienvenida, tanto los códigos como los mensajes de error, deben estar en formato texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, podrías mostrarnos cual es la linea que te marca como error y el mensaje completo, o tal vez la clase completa que tiene tu interfaz gráfica?

Comment: @zoeee77 de acuerdo a lo que describes y si usas netbeans, me parece saber cual es el problema, te sugiero que agregues una imagen donde se muestra el error y donde tratas de acceder al archivo para tratar de editarlo.